# iOS NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app crash with following error

```
 NSInvalidArgumentException [UIView _isScrollViewScrollObserver:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I set all exception breakpoint, but not give me any information, and I not have idea what kind of selector is _isScrollViewScrollObserver.

Comment: You must have made something a scrollview observer that isn't.

Comment: it happens when attach scrollview view content to my vc iboutlet that is a simple uiview dragged and dropped in storyboard.....i keep the same vc....I really doesn't understand iOS

Comment: Any idea about this? I really doesn't set nothing for view/scroll view/ vc....It happens when attacching view to iboutlet...